# How to call the scientists who work in the natural sciences?

Tags: expressions, sentence, names, technical, science

How to call the scientists who work in the natural, technical, biological and other sciences?
Can I call them natural scientists, technical scientists and so on?

Comment: What exactly does a "technical scientist" study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "natural scientist" is used rarely these days; more specific disciplines like chemist, physicist, biologist, astronomer, and earth scientist (stilted though it sounds) are more common.

For "technical scientist," one would more likely use the words engineer or technologist; I can't recall ever having heard the term before and I don't think it is a current English idiom.

"Biological scientist," and similar constructions, sound a bit overblown and flowery. Stick with the simpler "biologist" etc where they exist (although you may have to resort to "earth scientist" and "atmospheric scientist" since there aren't any good single-word description for those who study some of the natural scientist).

Comment: Naturalist is the old-fashioned terminology for this. Charles Darwin, for example, is frequently called a naturalist.

Answer (score 2):

The general terms used today are ***life sciences***, not ***biological sciences***, and ***physical sciences***, not ***natural sciences***. For ***technical sciences***, if you want to include *computer science, information science,* and *materials science*, there's no umbrella term for these with *science* in the name.

Usually, nobody refers to a single scientist as a *life scientist*; we would call them a *biologist* or a *microbiologist* or a *marine biologist* or an *entomologist* or a *botanist*  or a *neuroscientist*.  However, if you want to refer to researchers in the life sciences or the physical sciences as a group, I can't think of any better term than *life scientists* or *physical scientists*. These terms are both in use.

Comment: The very old-fashioned naturalist might work for biologists.

Comment: @David: For me, *naturalist* gives the impression of somebody who goes into the Amazon jungle and finds species nobody knew existed before, and not somebody who studies bacteria in a lab using microscopes and DNA sequencing tools. So it would include [Edmund O Wilson](http://www.amazon.com/Naturalist-Edward-O-Wilson/dp/1597260886), but not neuroscientists.

Comment: Yes, it harkens back to the days where most of the work was field work. I agree.